# Gradle check constant value to show error if true

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

There's any way to setup gradle to check a constant variable like DEBUG in the project and show an error if it is trying to do a release version?

Thanks

Comment: `BuildConfig.DEBUG` will never be true for a release build, so why not just rely on that?

Comment: There are other variable that I use inside my project beside the DEBUG one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend going about it a different way. Instead of hardcoding other variables and then having it throw a build error if they're set in release builds, set those variables in the build file, and give them different values for the debug and release build types. The facility for this is the `buildConfigField` directive, and that mechanism sets variables that act like `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

You can do something like this in your module's **build.gradle**:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {            
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_CONSTANT", '"debugValue"'
    }
    release {            
        buildConfigField "String", "MY_CONSTANT", '"releaseValue"'
    }
}
```

This will add a `BuildConfig.MY_CONSTANT` that will have the value "debugValue" for debug builds and "releaseValue" for release.

If you want to have different behavior in debug and release builds, in your code you can use conditionals on `BuildConfig.DEBUG` or on your constants:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // Do something here only for debug builds
}
```

etc.

Note that if you really don't want to set your variables in the build file, you could use that conditional pattern to initialize global static variables right in the code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    sGlobalVariable = "debug";
}
```