# Different parameters for dev and production environments using Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In an Android java project with Gradle build configured using Android Studio IDE, I want to have variables that change according to build environment.

For instance, if there's a `public static final boolean USE_LOCAL_BACKEND = false;` in Utils.java, production should always have `false` value and development may want to have `true` to use a local server for debugging.

I'm not an expert with Gradle, I'd appreciate a detailed guide on how to configure my project to have two different `properties` files for each environment, each has the same keys but with different values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489564/gradle-check-constant-value-to-show-error-if-true/26490982#26490982 should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution, by far, is to move `USE_LOCAL_BACKEND` into `BuildConfig`:

```
android {
    // other stuff here

    buildTypes {
        debug {
          buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://test.this-is-so-fake.com"'
        }

        release {
          buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://prod.this-is-so-fake.com"'
        }

        mezzanine.initWith(buildTypes.release)

        mezzanine {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://stage.this-is-so-fake.com"'
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I am defining a `SERVER_URL` `String` field on `BuildConfig` for three build types (`debug`, `release`, and a custom `mezzanine` one). You could do the same thing for a `boolean` `USE_LOCAL_BACKEND`. You would then refer to it in your Java code as `BuildConfig.USE_LOCAL_BACKEND`.

Comment: Cool, just for clarification this code sits in build.gradle and gets auto generated into BuildConfig.java class. Thanks!

Comment: @Kof: Yeah, sorry about the gaps, I was rushing my answer.