# On Android best place to keep settings like api url

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my android app, I need to keep the settings for the api url, that varies based on the type of build (I will have one for debug/staging and release). Keeping this into the `strings` file does not feel right since this folder has localized strings and there is nothing to localize about the api url.

What is the best place to keep this url in?

Comment: which build tool are you using ? ant ? gradle ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle check constant value to show error if true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489564/gradle-check-constant-value-to-show-error-if-true)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `BuildConfig` class, for example:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', 'http://...'
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', 'http://...'
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you don't want to store the URL's in `build.gradle`, you can use the `debug` and `release` folders to create a special class which stores the URL:

- `debug\src\java\com\myapp\ApiParam.java`
- `release\src\java\com\myapp\ApiParam.java`

Now, in your `main` project, you can reference the `ApiParam` class.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you didn't suggest string resources?

Comment: That will need context to access the base-url everytime

Answer (score 1):

Resource file are fine for that, you don't have to put in in all the translation folders and what is nice about them is that you can override them from a library project to the main project.

If you don't want to use them, then a sample class with a constant string.